# How to make input in create view as native widget

Tags: octobercms

Instead of default input control:
[image]

I want this: [image]

The second view (is it widget?) is used in default section `CMS`. How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek how RainLab.Blog plugin does it:

Posts controller: https://github.com/rainlab/blog-plugin/blob/master/controllers/Posts.php

Post toolbar partial: https://github.com/rainlab/blog-plugin/blob/master/controllers/posts/_post_toolbar.htm

Post field definitions: https://github.com/rainlab/blog-plugin/blob/master/models/post/fields.yaml